# How to correctly create std::string from a std::string_view?

Tags: c++, string, iterator, c++17, string-view

I have a class:

```
class Symbol_t {
public:
   Symbol_t( const char* rawName ) {
      memcpy( m_V, rawName, 6 * sizeof( char ) );
   };

   string_view strVw() const {
      return string_view( m_V, 6 );
   };

private:
   char m_V[6];

}; // class Symbol_t
```

and there is a lib-func that I can't modify:

```
extern bool loadData( const string& strSymbol );
```

If there is a local variable:

```
Symbol_t   symbol( "123456" );
```

When I need to call loadData, I dare not do it like this:

```
loadData( string( symbol.strVw().begin(), symbol.strVw().end() ) );
```

I have to do like this:

```
string_view svwSym = symbol.strVw();
loadData( string( svw.begin(), svw.end() ) );
```

My question:
Is the first method correct? or I must use the second one?

Because I think that in Method 1, the iterators I passed to the constructor of std::string, are of two Different string_vew objects, and theoretically the result is undefined, even though we would get expected result with almost all of the C++ compilers.

Any hints will be appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no need to use the c'tor taking a range. `std::string` has a constructor that operates in terms of `std::string_view`, [number 10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) in the list. The effect of which is

> ```
> template < class T >
> explicit basic_string( const T& t, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```
>
> Implicitly converts t to a string view sv as if by `std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> sv = t;`, then initializes the string with the contents of `sv`, as if by `basic_string(sv.data(), sv.size(), alloc)`. This overload only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>>` is true and `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, const CharT*>` is false.

Since both conditions hold for `std::string_view` itself, we can write the call to `loadData` as simply:

```
loadData( std::string( symbol.strVw() ) );
```

Comment: You said _implicitly_, but it is `explicit`, right?

Comment: @markus - The string c'tor is, obtaining a string_view is done implicitily *inside* this c'tor.

Answer (score 3):

If you have some string_view in C++ that you want to convert into string format (so you can return to a function after doing all your analyses, for example), you can make that change by doing this:

```
string_view sv;
string s = {sv.begin(), sv.end()};
```

Going the other way, to get a string_view from a string (so to get a pointer to that string) you can do this:

```
string s;
string_view sv = string_view(s);
```

Note that substring and a variety of other operations can be performed on string_view just as on string.

Comment: Doesn't this make a full copy of the string though? The primary purpose of `string_view` is to avoid doing exactly that.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 a `std::string` is a value type owning the memory for the string. Instanciating the `std::string` has to do a full-copy, because that is exactly what is requested by using this type.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the first method correct?

It is, since `strVw` returns identical `string_view`s: they all point to the same `m_V` and have the same size.

The correctness here depends on how `strVw` is implemented.

> or I must use the second one?

I would create a conversion function:

```
inline std::string as_string(std::string_view v) { 
    return {v.data(), v.size()}; 
}
```

And use that:

```
loadData(as_string(symbol.strVw()));
```

This method is safe regardless of `strVw` implementation.