# Is there really no explicit constructor of std::string from an std::string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view, explicit-conversion, explicit-constructor

Some (many?) programmers who are introduced to both `std::string_view` and `std::string` ask themselves: "Why can I convert the latter into  the former, but not the other way around?"

One part of the question is answered here:

[Why is there no implicit conversion from std::string_view to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525238)

and one can like or dislike the reasons. However - what about an *explicit* constructor? I don't see one on the [`std::string` constructors page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) on cppreference.com?

Both answers to questions regarding implicit constructors essentially state that an implicit constructor would cause an memory allocation and memory copy, which it's not clear the programmer desires. Ok, well, with an explicit constructor - the programmer *does* want the allocation and the copy. Why not give it to him/her?

Comment: There _is_ an explicit constructor of std::string from std::string_view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424817/3001761

Comment: To be percise there is an explicit c'tor from anything that is convertible to a string_view.

Comment: Per jonrsharpe, does this answer your question? [How to correctly create std::string from a std::string\_view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424390/how-to-correctly-create-stdstring-from-a-stdstring-view)

Comment: @DavisHerring: While the answer is almost identical, the questions are very different from each other. So, I think these shouldn't be dupes

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr: It actually does exist.

As @Barry and @StoryTeller indicate, this constructor actually exists - albeit through the use of templates; you're just failing to notice the "fine print" on the cppreference page you linked to:

```
template < class T >
explicit constexpr basic_string(
    const T& t,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()
);
```

this will construct an `std::string` from a `std::string_view`. Why? Because what it:

> Implicitly converts `t` to a string view `sv` as if by `std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> sv = t;`, then initializes the string with the contents of `sv`, as if by `std::basic_string(sv.data(), sv.size(), alloc)`.

For the specific case of `T = std::string_view`:

```
template <>
explicit constexpr basic_string<std::string_view>(
    const std::string_view& t,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()
);
```