# C++ - How are the arguments passed around in these lambdas?

Tags: c++, string, lambda, utf-8, string-view

I am taking a look at an Open Source repo with this file written in C++. The two functions use lambdas and callbacks, and I just want to better understand the order of operations and how they work together.

How is this block executed when `WindowScenarioselectOpen(scenarioselect_callback callback)` is called?

Here is the code block:

```
WindowBase* WindowScenarioselectOpen(scenarioselect_callback callback)
{
    return WindowScenarioselectOpen([callback](std::string_view scenario) { callback(std::string(scenario).c_str()); });
}

WindowBase* WindowScenarioselectOpen(std::function<void(std::string_view)> callback)
{
    auto* window = static_cast<ScenarioSelectWindow*>(WindowBringToFrontByClass(WindowClass::ScenarioSelect));
    if (window != nullptr)
    {
        return window;
    }

    int32_t screenWidth = ContextGetWidth();
    int32_t screenHeight = ContextGetHeight();
    ScreenCoordsXY screenPos = { (screenWidth - WW) / 2, std::max(TOP_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT + 1, (screenHeight - WH) / 2) };
    window = WindowCreate<ScenarioSelectWindow>(WindowClass::ScenarioSelect, screenPos, WW, WH, 0, callback);
    return window;
}
```

Also, `scenarioselect_callback` is defined in another file as `using scenarioselect_callback = void (*)(const utf8* path);`.

To my understanding, the call to the first windowscenarioselect defined a lambda that is passed into the second one. This lambda takes in a `string_view scenario`, which is used to construct a string, then converted to a C string with `c_str` , which is then passed into the `scenarioselect_callback` definition.

My confusion is I thought we can't construct a `string` from a `string_view`, and another question is, can `c_str`'s return which is a `char*` be used as a `utf8*`?

I am not so interested in the second function with a longer body, I am more interested in how the arguments are set up and work in order to make the second function work.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424390/how-to-correctly-create-stdstring-from-a-stdstring-view

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/4641116)

Comment: please improve the title of the question

Answer (score 0):

> My confusion is I thought we can't construct a string from a string_view,

There is no implicit conversion from a `std::string_view` to a `std::string`, this is true. However [an explicit conversion is allowed](https://godbolt.org/z/dzY9WcTY7):

```
std::string to_string(const std::string_view &sv)
{
    return std::string{sv};
}
```

An attempt to summon an implicit conversion with a plain `return sv;` won't work here, but an explicit construction is allowed. And does what's expected: a resulting `std::string` containing the same sequence as the defined `std::string_view`.

> can c_str's return which is a char* be used as a utf8*?

Nope. For starters, `c_str()` returns a `const char *` and not a `char *`.

> another file as using scenarioselect_callback = void (*)(const utf8* path);

Details matter. A `const utf8 *` is specified here, not `utf8 *`. A brief search of the C++ standard does not appear to find any mention of a type called `utf8` that's defined in the C++ library.

Occam's razor concludes that `utf8` is just your application code's `typedef` for a `char`, so you really have a `const char *` here, which `c_str()` is more than happy to return.